# ZeroClipboard JavaScript library throws Uncaught Error: Error calling method on NPObject

Tags: flash, zeroclipboard

I am trying to copy content to clipboard using https://github.com/zeroclipboard/ZeroClipboard. It seems a good library, but I am getting the error  **'Error calling method on NPObject.'** when the copy button (a flash) is hovered.

Seems like a flash security problem, but I am able to load the flash content.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it work. It was a same origin security model breech.
 My web apps subdomain was 'WWW' but the flash content was served from 'CDN'.
  Just rendered both the contents from same subdomain.

Find more @ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Gecko_Plugin_API_Reference/Scripting_plugins?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Gecko_Plugin_API_Reference%3AScripting_plugins#NPObject

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

In versions after 1.1.7, if you hosted "ZeroClipboard.swf" on a different domain than the hosting page, you need to set "allowScriptAccess" to "always" other than "sameDomain", also "trustedDomains" should contain current page domain.

```
ZeroClipboard.setDefaults( { moviePath:'http://YOURSERVER/path/ZeroClipboard.swf',allowScriptAccess: "always",trustedDomains: location.hostname } );
```

Comment: typo: hostaname should be hostname. Oh and thanks, this worked for me.

Comment: Note the use of `trustedDomains` rather than `trustedOrigins`. Even though `trustedDomains` is supposedly deprecated, I had to use it in order to get my setup to work (developing locally at `http://localhost:3000` and loading .swf from `"//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/zeroclipboard/1.1.7/ZeroClipboard.swf"`

Comment: Thanks for the additional information mate. forgot to change that line ;)

Answer (score 1):

Please add `"trustedDomains : [*]"`

Tha't how I fixed my problem.

```
var clip = new ZeroClipboard(document.getElementById("copy-button"), {
    trustedDomains: [ "*" ],
    moviePath: "http://assets.dev.alipay.net/gallery/zeroclipboard/1.2.2/ZeroClipboard.swf"
});
```

For more details: https://github.com/zeroclipboard/zeroclipboard/issues/103

Answer (score 0):

I just updated from 1.0.7 to 1.1.7 yesterday and I'm experiencing the same issue... I'm wondering if they broke something with a commit they did yesterday because this is the only post I've seen about the issue.

~Seth

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps anyone else, I managed to make this error go away for my setup (developing locally at `http://localhost:3000` and loading the Flash file from cdnjs. CoffeeScript:

```
if ZeroClipboard?
    ZeroClipboard.setDefaults
        moviePath: "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/zeroclipboard/1.1.7/ZeroClipboard.swf"
        trustedOrigins: [window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host]
        trustedDomains: window.location.hostname
        allowScriptAccess: "always"
```

Note that `trustedDomains` is the key here. Even though it's supposedly deprecated in 1.1.7, removing it (for me at least) causes the dreaded `Error calling method on NPObject` error to return.

Answer (score 0):

Or else your domain is not ssl secured i.e your protocol is `http` instead of `https` so you should alter your swf link from

> https://davidwalsh.name/demo/ZeroClipboard.swf

To

> http://davidwalsh.name/demo/ZeroClipboard.swf

For further details please check `Cross-Protocol Limitations` topic in the following documentation

http://www.kellyjandrews.com/zc/guides/limitations/protocol/